# AngularJS broadcast data to iframe

Tags: angularjs

How can I get the username from index.html?

index.html

`{{username}}`

index controller:

```
app.controller('index',function($scope,$rootScope,mainService){
    $scope.getUsername = funciton(){
        mainService.getUsername().then{
            function successCallback(response){
                $rootScope.username = response.data.username;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

iframe.html

`{{user}}`

iframe controller

```
app.controller('iframe',function($scope,$rootScope){
    $scope.user = $rootScope.username
})
```

but `{{user}}` show nothing

Also, I tried to post the message by Service like `dataService.username` result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$rootScope.$broadcast` to raise an event, first paramter for the event name and an optional second parameter to pass an argument.

```
app.controller('IndexController', function ($scope, $rootScope, MainService) {
    $scope.getUsername = function() {
        MainService.getUsername().then(function (response) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('username-fetched', { username: response.data.username });
        });
    };
});
```

Then catch the event on the other controller by using `$scope.$on`.

```
app.controller('IframeController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('username-fetched', function (event, data) {
        $scope.user = data.username;
    });
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work ,{{ussername}} just load one time when index.html loaded.(i use    ng-init to trigger getUsername()   meanwhile,the iframe.html has not been opened,when i open iframe.html .nothing changes